# Представить сразу несколько аргументов в функции

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Мне нужно два аргумента message: Message и call: types.CallbackQuery, но когда я их указываю - происходит ошибка `missing 1 required positional argument: 'call'` . Что с этим сделать?

```
async def csearc1h(message: Message, call: types.CallbackQuery):
```

Comment: добавь `=None` чтоб убрать ошибку, но тут просто колбэк не расчитан на передачу call

Comment: @eri Проблема в том, что я использую оба этих аргумента. Есть ещё какой-то способ решения?

Comment: как сервер должен понять что нужно положить во второй аргумент? доставай из контекста свё что нужно.